# Como verificar se determinado campo/valor existe no documento JSON?

Tags: java, java-8, gson

```
{
"timestamp":"2018-10-08T16:58:38.949Z",
"dataFrame":"QQ==",
"fcnt":15,
"freq":902500000,
"port":12,
"rssi":-69,
"snr":10,
"sf_used":10,
"session_id":"f41e10e8-1c73-499c-8ad7-4cbcd54c8ebd",
"gtw_info":[{
    "gtw_id":"000000000b0319a3",
    "rssi":-69,
    "snr":10},
    {
    "gtw_id":"000000000b031938",
    "rssi":-100,
    "snr":10.2,
    "gps_tmst":1539014318485}],
"id":1539017918949,
"dr_used":"SF10BW125",
"decrypted":true}
```

Minha aplicação recebe o JSON que acima, nesse Json existe o array "gtw_info", porém como podem notar os dados desse array nem sempre são os mesmo para cada posição. Gostaria de saber como posso verificar quando o campo "gps_tmst", por exemplo, existe ou não no array.

Comment: Você está utilizando alguma biblioteca para o tratamento?

Comment: Estou usando Gson, mas não encontrei nada relacionado a minha necessidade até agora.

Comment: se você está usando gson você poderia simplesmente transformar isso num objeto e trata-lo normalmente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando a API do Gson, o ideal seria você criar uma classe POJO que mapeasse todos os campos do seu json. A partir daí, bastaria você checar se determinado campo está nulo. [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38636254/how-to-convert-json-to-java-object-using-gson) você encontra um exemplo básico de como fazer, mas há dezenas de tutoriais disponíveis na internet.

Entretanto, se essa solução não é a que você procura, você pode adicionar ao seu projeto uma lib chamada Json (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20180813) e, usando-a, criar um objeto Json e, a seguir, navegando pelo objeto criado, verificar se o que você procura existe ou não.

Seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(seu_json_em_formato_String);
if(json.has("gtw_info")) {
  JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("gtw_info"); //recuperando gtw_info
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i); //cada objeto dentro de gtw_info
      if(object.has("gtw_id")) { //finalmente checa se o campo existe
      //sua logica aqui
      }
    }
}
```

Se sobrou dúvida, só perguntar.

Comment: MUIIIITO OBRIGADA! Funcionou exatamente como eu precisava. :D